# What is this 3-engine beast?

Tags: aircraft-identification, experimental-aircraft

What is this 3-engine beast? It has an unusual 6-bladed propeller as well.

[image: aircraft]

Comment: Hello Tiger, welcome to aviaiton.stackexchange.com. Can you credit the photographer and the source of the photograph and put in a link to the website where you found it? We appreciate it if people are credited for their work.

Answer (score 39):

Vickers Viscount C-FTID-X

Pratt & Whitney Canada's PT6 test bed with a PW100 mounted on the nose.

**01/22/2007. Remarks by Jack McKillop:**

> "This aircraft made its first flight on February 25, 1959 and was delivered to Trans Canada Air Lines (TCA) on March 8, 1959 registered CF-TID with fleet number '648'. TCA was renamed Air Canada on June 1, 1964. It was leased to The Sarcee Club between October 1971 and June 1972
>
> It was sold to United Aircraft of Canada on November 27, 1972, and reregistered C-FTID-X, it was used by Pratt & Whitney of Canada for flight-testing the PW124 turbo engine with six-bladed Hamilton Standard advanced propeller to power the British Aerospace ATP. In October 1989 it was withdrawn from service and stored at St. Hubert, Quebec. As of this date, the aircraft is no longer registered in Canada."

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks hideous!

Comment: It's obviously been lying to someone.

Comment: Well, that configuration *does* put the test engine and prop out in clean clear airflow, and.....and... erm...  Ok that's it, that's the *only* redeeming feature I can think of. That thing must be a total pain on takeoff and landing, it would induce the most interesting vibration modes in the airframe, and limits pilots to people with strong stomachs, prone to neither vomiting in disgust not falling down laughing at the sight of their vehicle. Deaf would help too, with a rather strong engine mounted directly in front of their cockpit and very little to dampen the noise.

Comment: Not the prettiest bird ever. And _5_ engine (not 3 as supposed by the OP) to boot! It's a test bed, though, and isn't designed to win beauty contests. Poor thing... I'll bet she's got a _great_ personality!

Comment: @PcMan I can't imagine that being deaf would help *much* considering the vibration...

Comment: I bet she's got the visibility of a Concode on landing.

Comment: @FreeMan "A plane called Sue"...

Comment: Wait... You're telling me that's not a plane that had a cargo container dropped on its nose?

Comment: I like the fact that someone's gone to the trouble to extend the paint job over the nose, including the racing stripe.  I suppose it was worth a try, but I don't think anything would help that.

Comment: Awesomely ugly. Might win "ugliest aircraft ever made", if it didn't get  too many people thinking it had  left ugly behind and progressed to surreal.

Comment: I wonder where that ugly dog rests now.